# Play-Services-Maps and Android Studio 3.3 issue with AndroidX involving Annotation library

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, androidx, android-studio-3.3

I've recently updated my project to build from Android Studio 3.3, which involved making the following changes (prompted on Android Studio startup):

build.gradle dependency:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'`

gradle-wrapper:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

This produced a number of errors in a feature module when trying to sync which uses Google Maps. I'm using version 16.0.0 of play-services-maps:

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"`

The errors that appeared when trying to sync gradle were:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':featureModule@flavorDebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':featureModule@flavorDebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':featureModule@flavorDebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':featureModule@flavorDebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.1.
```

This is repeated for every possible flavour variant combination in this module.

It's worth pointing out that this project was migrated to androidX some months ago and has been working fine.

The fix for the errors are to add the following to the gradle dependencies for that failing module:

```
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1"
implementation "androidx.core:core:1.0.1"
```

The app then compiles fine and runs on device. Perfect. Until we try and run lint in a CI build before release on the project, and we hit a spot of bother, with the error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':featureModule:lintFlavorDebug'.
> Lint infrastructure error
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
... [several lines omitted for brevity]
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected task 'processFlavorDebugAndroidTestJavaRes' output files to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:65)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getJavaResourcesForUnitTesting(BaseVariantData.java:700)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.createAndroidArtifact(ModelBuilder.java:992)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.createVariant(ModelBuilder.java:617)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAndroidProject(ModelBuilder.java:399)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.createAndroidProject(LintGradleExecution.java:352)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.analyze(LintGradleExecution.java:85)
    ... 59 more
```

This issue goes away if we remove the 2 new dependencies (plus Google Maps, which seems to be the cause of the requirement for the core and annotations libraries).

I've done some searching both here and via Google, and the `Expected task 'processFlavorDebugAndroidTestJavaRes' output files to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.` exception has been seen by others, and their solution is to make sure the base build.gradle file has the `baseFeature true` flag in `defaultConfig`, which is already present in my project.

I'm now stuck for where to go next in trying to solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried using api, replace implementation, else try to force one of the version of the library
api ('androidx.core:core:1.0.0') {
        force = true
    }.
I'm going through a similar issue with one of my modules and temporarily solved the issue this way. Hope it works for you

Comment: This does not work